# awk: emulate 'pr -mt file*'

Tags: text-processing, awk

While I was playing with `awk`'s multi file processing construct

```
awk 'NR == FNR { # some actions; next} # other condition {# other actions}' file*.txt
```

I asked myself, if it's possible to convert text files with different sizes for printing with `awk` like with

```
pr -mt file*
```

Assuming:

file1.txt

```
arbitrary text of the first file,
which is not so long.

More arbitrary text of the first file.
```

file2.txt:

```
Arbitrary text of the second file.
More arbitrary text of the second file.
More and More arbitrary text of the second file.
It's going on.
But finally every text will end.
```

The output sould be like this:

```
$ pr -w150 -mt file*
arbitrary text of the first file,         Arbitrary text of the second file.            
which is not so long.                     More arbitrary text of the second file.       
                                          More and More arbitrary text of the second file.  
More arbitrary text of the first file.    It's going on.                    
                                          But finally every text will end.
```

How to achieve this with `awk` command only with having on `file*.txt`?

Comment: Why would you want to do this with `awk` though? There are far better tools like `paste` or `pv` which you mentioned. You would have to write a dedicated awk script for this, and that's kinda too broad a question. If you really want to do this, start writing it and ask if you get stuck.

Comment: @terdon I know there are several easy and fancy ways to do this, even with `vim`. But while I was playing with `awk`'s multi file processing construct, I want to achieve this task with `awk`. If this would be impossible, I would accept the answer.

Comment: Not impossible, awk is a full programming language, you can write whatever you like in it. However, it will not be simple or practical and just, frankly, seems like a waste of time. Maybe someone will want to write it for you, but a far better approach would be to write it yourself and ask here if you have difficulty with a specific aspect of it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could record all the lines of every file, noting the maximum line length and number of lines for each and then print all the lines in the end:

```
awk '
  FNR == 1 {f++}
  {line[f, FNR] = $0}
  length > width[f] {width[f] = length}
  FNR > max_lines {max_lines = FNR}
  END{
    for (row = 1; row <= max_lines; row++) {
      for (i = 1; i <= f; i++)
        printf "%-*s", (i == f ? 0 : width[i] + 2), line[i, row]
      print ""
    }
  }' ./*.txt
```

Comment: This is __exactly__ what I was looking for and also very well explained. Thank you very much.